# Сетка на Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap4, grid

[image]

Как сделать это с помощью бутстрап 4?Всё съезжает, не получается.Задавать ширину и высоту блокам не всегда получается, иногда не задается почему-то. Дайте наводку или объясните хотя бы как сделать верхний левый кусок, там может сам додумаю

https://codepen.io/WatanabeTanya/pen/qBdVOwP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css-boo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1 block1">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1 block2">2</div>
            <div class=""></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row grey_block">
            <div class="col-1 block3">3</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
.block1{
    background: #a6b732;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.block2{
    background: #838383;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 80px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.block3{
    background: #fdc442;
    height: 80px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100px;
}
.grey_block{
    width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Блоки не получается расставить как надо. Все едет.

Comment: Вы видите, что у вас пять строк и пять столбцов? https://i.stack.imgur.com/jE2YO.png (и ещё две вертикальные линии забыл прочертить, но смысл думаю понятен)

Comment: https://codepen.io/WatanabeTanya/pen/xxGPeBz     вот так? на кодпене как-то не так показывает. https://imgur.com/a/r0Bbt8P  вот как в браузере получилось. как теперь поменять их размер? высоту указываю - меняется, ширина- нет.